# unable to read a data from a external JSON file : Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have configured all the URL's in a JSON file called `ionic-config.JSON`. The data is like

```
[
    {
        "db_url": "http://localhost:3000/users/"
    }
]
```

I'm the trying to read the data using the `GET` method.

```
url: string = '../ionic-config/ionic-config.json';
this.http.get(this.url).subscribe( (data: any) => {
      this.db_url = data;
    })
```

But I'm getting an error as 404 no found

> GET http://localhost:8100/ionic-config/ionic-config.json 404 (Not
>   Found)

The file is in the directory `src/ionic-config/ionic-config.json`

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of the following ways.

### 1. Using an Api Call

a. Just move the `ionic-config.json` file to assets folder for better code flow.Then make the api call like this.

```
return this.http.get('assets/ionic-config.json')
    .map(res=> return res.json);
```

b. in your `.ts file` subscribe for the api call like this

```
<method_name_in_service_file>.subscribe(resp=>{
 this.db_url = resp;
},error=>{
   console.log(error)
})
```

### 2. Directly import from the ionic-config file

like this

```
import * as dbUrl from '<path to the config file>'
```

you will get the url from `dbUrl[0].db_url`

Comment: I've tried it using the keyword `import` as `import * as dbUrl from '../assets/ionic-config.json';` But I'm getting the error as `Cannot find module '../assets/ionic-config.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension` . I have pasted the json file in the assets folder.

Comment: Just use assets/<filename>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with your path.

Try this:

```
url: string = 'ionic-config/ionic-config.json';
```

Also, your logic for assigning the value of db_url is wrong. You are assigning the whole array rather than the field of a specific object in the array. Use this instead:

```
this.db_url = data[0].db_url;
```

Comment: I've tried it there is no change in the error. I'm calling it from the service file. The directory is as `src/services/AU.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to make a http request to the same server. To use a JSON file within your App:

For example if your JSON File is in **`/src/pages/YourPage/myJson.json`** the go to your `YourPage.ts`(in the same folder as your JSON) and say `import * as jsonData from './myJson.json';`

Now you can use it as normal JSON object without to parse it.

For example: (because your JSON is an Array of Objects):

```
console.log(jsonData[0].db_url);
```

Comment: I've tried it using the keyword `import` as `import * as dbUrl from '../assets/ionic-config.json';` But I'm getting the error as `Cannot find module '../assets/ionic-config.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension` . I have pasted the json file in the assets folder.

Comment: I see your error. Try `import * as dbUrl from '../../assets/ionic-config.json'`

Comment: Your link referred to the wrong folder, but now it should work

Comment: No, I use directed to the folder properly. I use vscode it shows dropdowns so I have navigated correctly. I have tried your code also it shows the same error.